# Copy Row of Data from One Worksheet to Another Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would need to copy a row of data from Worksheet A to Worksheet X. I have multiple worksheets and these rows from each worksheet will form a summary in Worksheet X. When someone enters new data in the worksheets, worksheet X need to be updated. Is it possible to do it without VBA or Macro?

Comment: no other alternative other than this? i am unfamiliar with html/macro/vba.

Comment: Power query might be an alternative too. However without any sample data it's not possible to give you detailed information

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the data for A1 is monitored and updated into worksheet X in each worksheet.

You just need to use a formula like the following in worksheet X:

```
=Sheet4!A1
```

When the valuein in A1 changes, the corresponding is updated in worksheet X.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand that this is one of the possible ways. I need to create this on a daily basis e.g. 11/08, 12/08, 13/08 and so on. Data entry for each day will be like from test1-test9 and this is repeated for everyday for the whole month. I understand that this method would be very manual.

Comment: you can copy down the formula.  you can copy it down 100 rows or as far ass you you think it is needed.  IS data only added to Worksheet A to the bottom of the last row recorded?